# Error keeps showing while I try to merge shapefiles

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, merge

I am trying to merge shapefiles (I have multiple of them in one folder) but it keeps returning this error. I'm not sure what that means. I didn't change the path or the data.

```
import arcpy, os 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=1 
arcpy.env.workspace="C:/Users/data" 

fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for shapefile in fc:
    if arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","Polygon"):
       arcpy.Merge_management(fc,"merge_poly.shp")
    elif arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","Point"):
       arcpy.Merge_management(fc,"merge_point.shp")
    elif arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","Line"):
       arcpy.Merge_management(fc,"merge_line.shp")
    else:
        print("cannot merge")
```

> ERROR 002948: The shape type of C:/Users/data\obce.shp is not the same as that of previously entered datasets.
> Failed to execute (Merge).

Comment: You cannot merge layers from differing topology classes. Your `if` tests are faulty.

Answer (score 1):

when you look at the list, you are not selecting the feature type but checking that the feature type is present in the entire list. I recommand to apply a filter based on the feature type to create your list, and you can test that the list is not empty to avoid errors.

```
if len(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","Polygon"))>0:
    arcpy.Merge_management(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","Polygon"),"merge_poly.shp")
if len(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","Point"))>0:
    arcpy.Merge_management(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","Point"),"merge_point.shp")
```

rem 1: using elif, you would only merge the polygons even if you have several lines or several points, therefore I suggest to use only "if"
rem 2: merging if you have only one feture of one type is useless, except that it copies the file with your standard naming. You could use "> 1" instead of "> 0"

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know how to make it all work together. This really helped, it works, thank you.